# How to use List<object> in response to API - C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I trying to convert this JSON API (http://194.141.118.43:3000/?date=2022-03-22&id=400&daysForward=8) to C# object here: https://json2csharp.com/

I receive `List<object> aladinModel { get; set; }`

How to use this List aladinModel in my response with API here:

```
 public async Task List<AladinModel> GetWeatherData(string query)
    {
        List<AladinModel> weatherData = new List<AladinModel>();
        try
        {
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(query);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                weatherData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AladinModel>(content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("\t\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return weatherData;
    }
```

This line is not correct:

```
public async Task List<AladinModel> GetWeatherData(string query)
```

How to use this List here ?

===============================================================

**UPDATE**

===============================================================

The object class look like:

```
 class ItemsAPI
{
    public partial class RootAladinModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("aladinModel")]
        public AladinModel[] AladinModel { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class AladinModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("DATS")]
        public DateTimeOffset Dats { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("TA")]
        public double Ta { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("RH")]
        public double Rh { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("WS")]
        public double Ws { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("RR")]
        public double Rr { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("SR")]
        public double Sr { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("APRES")]
        public double Apres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The RestService class look like:

```
 public async Task<List<AladinModel>> GetAladinData(string query)
    {
        List<AladinModel> weatherData = new List<AladinModel>();
        try
        {
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(query);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                weatherData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AladinModel>>(content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("\t\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return weatherData;
    }
```

but I receive error:

```
    {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[pizhevsoft.Models.ItemsAPI+AladinModel]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'aladinModel', line 1, position 15.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) [0x003a0] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) [0x0006d] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x000db] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00054] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x0002d] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value) [0x00000] in <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0 
  at pizhevsoft.Services.RestServiceAPI.GetAladinData (System.String query) [0x00151] in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\pizhevsoft\pizhevsoft\pizhevsoft\pizhevsoft\Services\RestServiceAPI.cs:30 }
```

Comment: Don't use json2csharp: it's a _tool of last resort_. Get a proper Swagger or OpenAPI definition file from the developers of that web-service directly.

Comment: Doesn't meter. I just want to know how to use this List of object in my Task ?

Comment: @Dai I thought you were a contributor to j2cs ?

Comment: @BlagovestPizhev "Doesn't meter." - I'll say that I disagree and that **it does matter**, because `object` is not a useful DTO type, it can even be dangerous if you're blindly deserializing JSON. "I just want to know how to use this List of object in my Task" - no, you should **not** be using `List<object>`. Json2CSharp uses the `object` type as a catch-all to make-up for C#'s lack of built-in support for union types - you should use the j2c code only as an initial scaffold which you then should _manually_ extend to represent polymorphic DTO types.

Comment: Ok, can you give me the object properties and show me how to use the object in the async task ?

Comment: your response is a single object, not a list of objects.  You need to deserialize `AladinModel` not `LIst<AladinModel>`

Comment: @jai quit trying to put down other's lib's I've used the library you are referring to and it's not bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This line is not correct:

> `public async Task List<AladinModel> GetWeatherData(string query)`

Indeed, it's a syntax error, and should have `<>` around the List:

```
public async Task<List<AladinModel>> GetWeatherData(string query)
```

It looks like json2csharp can't understand that JSON very well. QuickType.io has a more involved go at it:

```
// <auto-generated />
//
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using SomeNamespace;
//
//    var someRootClassName = SomeRootClassName.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class SomeRootClassName
    {
        [JsonProperty("aladinModel")]
        public List<AladinModelUnion> AladinModel { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class PurpleAladinModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("DATS")]
        public DateTimeOffset Dats { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("TA")]
        public double Ta { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("RH")]
        public double Rh { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("WS")]
        public double Ws { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("RR")]
        public double Rr { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("SR")]
        public double Sr { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("APRES")]
        public double Apres { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class FluffyAladinModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("fieldCount")]
        public long FieldCount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("affectedRows")]
        public long AffectedRows { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("insertId")]
        public long InsertId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("serverStatus")]
        public long ServerStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("warningCount")]
        public long WarningCount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("protocol41")]
        public bool Protocol41 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("changedRows")]
        public long ChangedRows { get; set; }
    }

    public partial struct AladinModelUnion
    {
        public FluffyAladinModel FluffyAladinModel;
        public List<PurpleAladinModel> PurpleAladinModelArray;

        public static implicit operator AladinModelUnion(FluffyAladinModel FluffyAladinModel) => new AladinModelUnion { FluffyAladinModel = FluffyAladinModel };
        public static implicit operator AladinModelUnion(List<PurpleAladinModel> PurpleAladinModelArray) => new AladinModelUnion { PurpleAladinModelArray = PurpleAladinModelArray };
    }

    public partial class SomeRootClassName
    {
        public static SomeRootClassName FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeRootClassName>(json, SomeNamespace.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this SomeRootClassName self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, SomeNamespace.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                AladinModelUnionConverter.Singleton,
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }

    internal class AladinModelUnionConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(AladinModelUnion) || t == typeof(AladinModelUnion?);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.StartObject:
                    var objectValue = serializer.Deserialize<FluffyAladinModel>(reader);
                    return new AladinModelUnion { FluffyAladinModel = objectValue };
                case JsonToken.StartArray:
                    var arrayValue = serializer.Deserialize<List<PurpleAladinModel>>(reader);
                    return new AladinModelUnion { PurpleAladinModelArray = arrayValue };
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type AladinModelUnion");
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var value = (AladinModelUnion)untypedValue;
            if (value.PurpleAladinModelArray != null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value.PurpleAladinModelArray);
                return;
            }
            if (value.FluffyAladinModel != null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value.FluffyAladinModel);
                return;
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot marshal type AladinModelUnion");
        }

        public static readonly AladinModelUnionConverter Singleton = new AladinModelUnionConverter();
    }
}
```

To use it you could probably have a code like:

```
public async Task<List<AladinModelUnion>> GetAladinData(string query)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync(query);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var someRootClassName = SomeRootClassName.FromJson(jsonString);
            return someRootClassName.AladinModel;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("\t\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }

    return null;
}
```

But I do think you should look at Dai's recommendation here; auto-tools are clearly struggling with the task of reverse engineering this rather-more-wacky-than-normal block of JSON (I've never personally seen QT generate anything like it has here - it's clearly a use case foreseen by the QT devs tho, so if you're happy with it/don't feel having an OA spec would offer anything more helpful...)

Comment: `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)` <-- This should also check for the response header `Content-Type: application/json`, otherwise some default HTML-based response will cause the JSON parsing to fail instead of gracefully handling unexpected server responses.

Comment: `public partial struct AladinModelUnion` <-- Thesedays, all `struct` types should be `readonly struct`. I'm disappointed that's not the default behavior today.

Comment: I think your method is correct but is too long for 7 properties. I cut part of your code but I receive a mistake I can't explain. Can you check my updated question, please.

Comment: I think Xamarin was on my limit; when exceptions mention JNI it's r/whoosh! Probably  better to ask it as a new question